# Gtk Hello World in Genie from Vala code

Tags: gtk, vala, genie

I wanted to reproduce a small Hello World Gtk program in Genie language, based in the following Vala code:

```
using Gtk;

int main(string[] args){
Gtk.init (ref args);
Gtk.Window window = new Gtk.Window (Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL);
Gtk.Label label = new Gtk.Label("Hello world!");
window.add(label);
    window.set_default_size (300, 200);
    window.show_all ();
Gtk.main ();
return 0;
}
```

How would the same code look in Genie?

Comment: Please ask more specific questions of what you have tried and what doesn't work in the future. "Give me the code" is normally not the kind of question used on stackoverflow.com

Comment: Ok, Jens, thanks... won't happen again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would look like this:

```
[indent=4]
uses Gtk

init
    Gtk.init (ref args)
    var window = new Window (WindowType.TOPLEVEL)
    var label = new Label("Hello world!")
    window.add(label)
    window.set_default_size (300, 200)
    window.show_all ()
    Gtk.main ()
```

Note that `args` is implicitly available.

I have used type inference when assigning the `window` and `label` identifiers. This is because the type is made clear on the right hand side.

You can be explicit about the type by stating the type after the identifier. The identifier and type are separated by a colon:

```
    window:Window = new Window (WindowType.TOPLEVEL)
    label:Label = new Label ("Hello world!")
```

Tabs are the default for indentation in Genie, but Stack Overflow insists on four and only multiples of four spaces. If you wish to use TABs for HTML examples of Genie code then the HTML TAB entity &#9; works well. Even in the preview for Stack Overflow. In this example, however, [indent=4] has to be used at the beginning.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Both languages really look alike, I am impressed. So, should I consider that Geanie has the same potential and power as Vala? I take an issue with the curly brackets from vala, it makes the code less readable, and this example makes it clear...

Comment: Genie has the same potential as Vala because underneath it is using the same Vala compiler, but Genie aims to be a cleaner syntax. Genie is currently not as powerful as Vala because it needs a bit more development, for example anonymous functions only work in a very limited circumstance. Take a look at the Genie bugs to get a better idea of some of the limits:
https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Genie/Developing

Comment: However Genie is less frequently used and the compiler still has several issues, you might consider using Vala especially as a beginner in the GLib/Gtk+ world.